# Why comunity general telegram ansible got this problem?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I want to configure ansible playbook, put some code for start the service and send notification to the telegram but I got this error. I think this is not typing error but there is something error with the community general telegram. Before this I already run the same process but got no error. Now I try reinstall new server and do the same process and I got this error.

```
 ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.telegram'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/playbook/start.yml': line 10, column 6, but maybe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


   - name: send notify to telegram
     ^ here
```

**start.yml**

```
---
- name: testing playbook
  hosts: server
  tasks:
   - name: start apache service
     service:
      name: apache2
      state: started

   - name: send notify to telegram
     community.general.telegram:
      token: 'telegram token'
      api_args:
       chat_id: telegramid
       parse_mode: "markdown"
       text: "Apache Web service has been started!"
       disable_web_page_preview: True
       disable_notification: True
```

**Installation process**

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu trusty main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt install dirmngr -y
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 93C4A3FD7BB9C367
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y ansible
sudo ansible-galaxy collection install community.general
```

**Ansible Version**

```
ansible 2.9.27
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

**sudo ansible-galaxy collection install community.general**

```
Process install dependency map
Starting collection install process
Skipping 'community.general' as it is already installed
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html#using-collections-in-playbooks) you need to add `collection` keyword

But also from the documentation for 2.9 version of the module [telegram](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/telegram_module.html) you can do it without collection.

So, either use:

```yaml
collections:
  - community.general
```

or

```yaml
   - name: send notify to telegram
     telegram:
      token: 'telegram token'
      api_args:
       chat_id: telegramid
       parse_mode: "markdown"
       text: "Apache Web service has been started!"
       disable_web_page_preview: True
       disable_notification: True
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

To use a newer version of `community.general` with Ansible `2.9`, you would need to use, the following syntax, that is the real `FQCN` of that module:

```yaml
community.general.notification.telegram
```

This problem is happening with many other modules, like:

```yaml
community.general.system.puppet
community.general.files.filesize
```

For a complete reference, check [Github's project page](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/tree/main/plugins/modules).

There's a discussion about it [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/77937) too.